# In-App Purchase to populate Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, in-app-purchase

I have a simple apps which stores values in a few Core Data tables.  I would like to use in-app purchases to populate additional records, but I'm not sure what the best practice would be for this.

A collection of records represents a race.  As the user downloads a new race, the images should be stored and the race details should be stored in the Core Data tables.

I have started the process to deliver new races via non-consumable in-app purchases.  The images are logically added to the supporting files.

How should I handle Core Data updates?  Should I include a plist in my package?  JSON files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both plist and JSON files are viable options. This is what I would go with.

Alternatively, if the levels are likely not to change, you could also include all levels in your original core data store and mark them as unlocked if an In-App purchase is successful.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The races will change over time, so I can't load them all as locked.